# How to regex for a numerical suffix?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex (example is in Python):

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^(([a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+)([\d]+)|([\d]+))$')
```

This correctly parses any string that has a numerical suffix and an optional prefix that is alphanumerics:

```
a123
a2a123
123
```

All will correctly see `123` as a suffix. It will correctly reject bad inputs:

```
abc
123abc
()123  # Or other non-alphanumerics
```

The regex itself is fairly unwieldy, though, and several of the capture groups are often empty as a result, meaning I have to go through the additional step of filtering them out. I am curious if there is a better way to be thinking about this regex than "a number OR a number preceeded by an alphanumeric that ends in a character"?

Comment: Are you aware of the existence of non-capturing groups?

Comment: Maybe `^[A-Za-z0-9]*?([0-9]+)$` will do. Or, `^(?:[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z])?(\d+)$`

Comment: @iBug I was not in any real sense, but reading on that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]*?([0-9]+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aCoDlc/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9]*?` - any letters/digits, zero or more times, as few as possible (due to this non-greedy matching, the next pattern, `([0-9]+)`, will match all digits at the end of the string there are)
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

In Python:

```
m = re.search(r'^[A-Za-z0-9]*?([0-9]+)$') # Or, see below
# m = re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9]*?([0-9]+)$') # re.match only searches at the start of the string
# m = re.fullmatch(r'[A-Za-z0-9]*?([0-9]+)') # Only in Python 3.x 
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Comment: It did not occur to me to use a `?` after a `*`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you use non-capturing groups and a correct management of repetitions, the problem eases itself.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+)?([0-9]+)$')
```

There's only one capturing group (group 1) for the suffix, and the alphanumerics before it is not captured.

Alternatively, using named groups is another option, and it often makes long, structured regexes easier to maintain:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^(?P<a>[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+)?(?P<suffix>[0-9]+)$')
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the non-capturing group! Feeling a bit dumb, but learnt!

Comment: However, I'd suggest ``^(?:[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z])?([0-9]+)$`` as in my comment to the question. Less backtracking and no redundant character class in the capturing group. Besides, `[0-9]` will only match ASCII digits, while `\d` may match any Unicode digits (default behavior in Python 3.x).